# writing mocha test for ember for first time, visit function missing

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js

I am trying to learn mocha testing for the first time. I wrote a simple test script like :

```
describe('Analytics Test Suite', function(){
//http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/
before(function() {
    AS.rootElement = '#ember-application-container';
    AS.setupForTesting();
    AS.injectTestHelpers();
    AS.reset();
});

describe('visit analytics index page', function(){
    visit("/analytics").then(function() {
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(4)).to.be(-1);
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(0)).to.be(-1);
        })
    });
})
});
```

But I am get this js error:

**ReferenceError: visit is not defined**

But if I modify the code to :

```
describe('Analytics Test Suite', function(){

AS.rootElement = '#ember-application-container';
AS.setupForTesting();
AS.injectTestHelpers();
AS.reset();


describe('visit analytics index page', function(){
    visit("/analytics").then(function() {
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(4)).to.be(-1);
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(0)).to.be(-1);
        })
    });
})
});
```

I get these errors:
**TypeError: app._*container*_.lookup(...) is undefined**

In the first scene the visit function seems to be missing which gets resolved when putting the initialization code outside of before. But then I get the type error, I think it should have looked for AS._*container*_lookup, but its looking at app namespace. I am using ember debug version http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0/ember.js

Your help will be much appreciated. I have also added jsbin http://jsbin.com/ILUbuy/2/.

Thanks,
Dee

**UPDATE**
I solved my problem adding this adapter : https://github.com/teddyzeenny/ember-mocha-adapter

Comment: For anyone trying to setup this same setup, make sure to remove any `done()` statements that you'd use with `mocha` if you are using the `ember-mocha-adapter`.

Comment: Please add detail your solution in an answer to your own question. (Yes, you can do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to follow up this post with a jsbin to a working example. When I first started testing ember app in firefox, I noticed I would always get this error:

```
"before each" hook ‣
     router is undefined
```

but this would not happen in chrome. My lead just found out what I was not doing right or what I was missing. Basically mocha was not finding the div where it should run the application when mocah.run() is executed, so a simple solution was :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    mocha.run();
});
```

Another error that I got and had no clew why I was getting was :

```
router.getHandler is not a function
```

turned out this was caused because I did not add App.reset(); in my beforeEach hook.

There was this one instance where I had to test if a div was toggling(using jquery UI, .tollge('slow')) on click or not. The problem was the test would run successfully but then following tests would always fail, I could never understand why this was happening. I knew that it was due to jquery UI stuff because if I set the visibility directly to the div without using fancy effect the tests would run, so if you have something similar happening where internally we are using setTimeouts, to test it do something like this:

```
 it("some test", function () {
    var context = this;            

    click(toggleButton).then(function () {
        Ember.run.later(context, function () {

        }, 1000);
        wait().then(function () {
            expect(DIV TO BE HIDDEN OR VISIBLE);
        });
    });
});
```

This link was super helpful too : http://instructure.github.io/blog/2014/01/24/ember-run-loop-and-tdd/

OK here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/opuJetOy/1/
The above link does not work in chrome, it seems like chrome does not like links like :
'https://raw.github.com/....', but it works in firefox.

Comment: If you could find the solution to your problem, please accept your answer. It makes easy for others who visit this question.